# mi codigo da una respuesta pero no la otra

Tags: python

mi código de **pyhton** la ingresar una entrada me da la respuesta que necesito pero la otra no y ya no se que hacer

Ejercicio 1:

**El valor de una hora de trabajo normal se obtiene dividiendo el salario base sobre 192**. Este valor corresponde a la jornada laboral establecida en el contrato (48 horas a la semana y 4 semanas al mes).
Las **horas extras se liquidan con un recargo del 25%** sobre el valor de una hora normal
Debido a buen desempeño de un empleado la empresa ocasionalmente otorga **bonificaciones del 5%** del salario base
El salario total antes de descuentos se calcula como **la suma del salario base, más el valor de las horas extras, más las bonificaciones** (si las hay)
Se descontará **3.5%** del salario total antes de descuentos para el plan obligatorio de salud
Se descontará **4%** del salario total antes de descuentos para el aporte a pensión
Se descontará **1%** del salario total antes de descuentos para caja de compensación.
Luego de considerar toda esta información, decide construir un programa que permita a cualquier empleado de la empresa verificar si los pagos son correctos.

siendo las siguientes entradas obligatorias **1000000 0 0** y **2355255 2 1** y sus respuestas ser **915000.0** y **2290871.9** respectivamente, pero solo me da el primer resultado el segundo me da 2268423.3723046877,
también probar si con **1 1 1 da 1.0**

```
#sal= salario, cant= cantidad, bonif= bonificacion, val= valor
sal_base, cant_horas, bonif = input().split()
sal_base, cant_horas, bonif = float(sal_base), float(cant_horas), float(bonif)

val_horas_normal = sal_base / 192
val_horas_extra = val_horas_normal * (25/100)
total_horas_extra = cant_horas * val_horas_extra

if bonif >=  1:
  val_bonif = sal_base * (5/100)
else:
  val_bonif = 0

sal_total = sal_base + total_horas_extra + val_bonif

salud = sal_total * (3.5/100)
pension = sal_total * (4/100)
caja = sal_total * (1/100)

sueldo_fijo = sal_total - salud - pension - caja
print(sueldo_fijo)
```

Comment: El error lo tienes en el cálculo de `val_horas_extra`. El enunciado dice " Las horas extras se liquidan con un recargo del 25% sobre el valor de una hora normal" es decir, 25% más, y tú estas calculando el 25% del valor de las horas normales, deberías multiplicar por `1.25` no por `0.25`. Y la razón por la que la primera respuesta si te da correctamente es porque en los datos de entrada no hay horas extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usarlo de esta manera

```
val_horas_extra = val_horas_normal * 1.25

val_bonif = sal_base * 0.05
```

Como las horas extras son un 25% más, debes multiplicar por 1.25. Y la bonificación es un 5% del salario base, así que multiplicas por 0.05 (que es 5/100).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).